# Pandas rowwise partial matching with any item from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a rowwise partial match in pandas dataframe so that if any of the terms from a list matches any word from a column. For example,
I have a dataframe df_x

```
             name            terms_list
0       acupuncturist   [acupuncturist, acupuncture]
1  seafood restaurant                [seafood, fish]
2         pet daycare                 [pet, dog, k9]
3  seafood restaurant                   [restaurant]
4     seafood grocery                   [restaurant]
```

which should have an output like below

```
        match
0       yes
1       yes
2       yes
3       yes
4       no
```

I tried

```
df_x[df_x.apply(lambda x: df_x['name'] in df_x['terms_list'], axis=1)]
```

But getting an error as `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'` . How can I resolve this error? Is there a better way to do this.

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['acupuncturist', 'seafood restaurant', 'pet daycare', 'seafood restaurant', 'seafood grocery'],
                   'terms_list': [['acupuncturist', 'acupuncture'], ['seafood', 'fish'], ['pet', 'dog', 'k9'], ['restaurant'], ['restaurant']]
                  })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set` operations:

```
df['mask'] = [bool(set(n.split())&s) for n, s in
              zip(df['name'], df['terms_list'].apply(set))]
```

Output:

```
                 name                    terms_list   mask
0       acupuncturist  [acupuncturist, acupuncture]   True
1  seafood restaurant               [seafood, fish]   True
2         pet daycare                [pet, dog, k9]   True
3  seafood restaurant                  [restaurant]   True
4     seafood grocery                  [restaurant]  False
```

For yes/no:

```
df['mask'] = ['yes' if bool(set(n.split())&s) else 'no' for n, s in
              zip(df['name'], df['terms_list'].apply(set))]
```

Output:

```
                 name                    terms_list mask
0       acupuncturist  [acupuncturist, acupuncture]  yes
1  seafood restaurant               [seafood, fish]  yes
2         pet daycare                [pet, dog, k9]  yes
3  seafood restaurant                  [restaurant]  yes
4     seafood grocery                  [restaurant]   no
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `lambda` function, you want to use the local variable for the rows:

```
mask = df_x.apply(lambda x: x['name'] in x['terms_list'], axis=1)
```

Alternatively, you can do a zip comprehension

```
mask = [x in y for x,y in zip(df_x['name'], df_x['terms_list'])]
```

Then finally,

```
df['output'] = np.where(mask, 'yes', 'no')
```

**note**: Not the exact answer as you wish; this is just a principle of `apply`. Go for mozway's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something like this:

```py
df_x.apply(lambda x: any(name_split in x['terms_list'] for name_split in x['name'].split()), axis=1)
```

This splits up each `name` and returns true if any word within name matches your list of terms.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
import re

df['match'] = [
    np.where(
        any(re.search(z, r'\b' + y['name'] + r'\b') 
            for z in y['terms_list']),
        'yes', 'no')
    for _, y in df.iterrows()]
```

Output:

```
                 name                    terms_list match
0       acupuncturist  [acupuncturist, acupuncture]   yes
1  seafood restaurant               [seafood, fish]   yes
2         pet daycare                [pet, dog, k9]   yes
3  seafood restaurant                  [restaurant]   yes
4     seafood grocery                  [restaurant]    no
```